# Decimal value error on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, savechanges

I need to store a value taken from a form into a column which is a `decimal(4,0)`.

First (in the controller) I take the value from the form and I convert it from string to decimal and multiply it for 100 so I'm able to keep the values I need

```
//"12.34" --> (12.34)*100 --> 1234
item.DECIMAL_VALUE = decimal.Parse(view.decimal_value) * 100;
```

I checked in debug mode: the value into `item.DECIMAL_VALUE` is effectively a decimal and its value is `1234` (as expected).

Going on with the code I come to the point where I need to save the value into the database

```
_context.TABLE.Add(item);
return _context.SaveChanges();
```

And that's the problem. I get a DbUpdateException because it tries to save `1234,00` (which doesn't correspond to the `decimal(4,0)`) instead of `1234`

Any ideas on why it's doing it and how to solve?

Comment: Why exactly would you use 4,0? That's a simple integer.

Comment: I can't change anything on the DB so I have to use 4,0 even if I don't like it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick to `decimal(4,0)` which is practically an integer you should also change the type of  the variable `DECIMAL_VALUE` to a true integer in the item class.

After that, just to avoid potential retyping problems, you should also use explicit retyping when assigning the value...

```
item.DECIMAL_VALUE = (int)(decimal.Parse(view.decimal_value) * 100);
```

Comment: Changing the type of `DECIMAL_VALUE` just got me more errors so I tried to keep it as it is and set its value as you suggested with `item.DECIMAL_VALUE = (int)(decimal.Parse(view.decimal_value) * 100);` and now it works! Thank you :) The only thing I can't understand is why was it adding the two zeroes? I have other decimal like that and I never got this problem

Comment: I don't know how it works but one might guess that it calls .ToString() function on the variable which (in case of decimal type) results in formatting with two decimal numbers.

The reason why you had to use the (int) is quite simple, btw. While c# has some sort of implicit retyping it works only in cases where no data can be lost (e.g. int to decimal). In this case, however, data can be lost (decimal info) so you have to specify that you really want to do it (assign decimal value into an int).